# Need to get HTML source as string CEFPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, cefpython

I am trying to get HTML source as string from web URL using CEFPython
I want `MainFrame`'s source content to be crawled and get string in

```python
def save_screenshot(browser):    
    # Browser object provides GetUserData/SetUserData methods
    # for storing custom data associated with browser. The
    # "OnPaint.buffer_string" data is set in RenderHandler.OnPaint.
    buffer_string = browser.GetUserData("OnPaint.buffer_string")
    if not buffer_string:
        raise Exception("buffer_string is empty, OnPaint never called?")
    mainFrame = browser.GetMainFrame()
    print("Main frame is ", mainFrame)
    # print("buffer string" ,buffer_string)

    # visitor object
    visitorObj = cef_string()
    temp = mainFrame.GetSource(visitorObj).GetString()
    print("temp : ", temp)

    visitorText = mainFrame.GetText(temp)
    siteHTML = mainFrame.GetSource(visitorText)
    print("siteHTML is ", siteHTML)
```

**Problem:**
The code is returning nothing for siteHTML

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cefpython/3PQTYUqa8YQ/discussion

Comment: Thanks. But do you have any working example for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mainframe.GetSource(visitor)` is asynchronous. Therefore you cannot call `GetString()` from it.

This is the way to do, unfortunately you need to think in asynchronous manner:

```python
class Visitor(object)
    def Visit(self, value):
        print("This is the HTML source:")
        print(value)
myvisitor = Visitor()
mainFrame = browser.GetMainFrame()
mainFrame.GetSource(myvisitor)
```

One more thing to beware of: the visitor object `myvisitor` in the above example is passed on to `GetSource()` in weak reference. In other words, you must keep that object alive until the source is passed back. If you put the last three lines in the above snippet in a function, you have to make sure the function does not return until the job is done.

Comment: Thanks. Did you run and check?

Comment: Not your code, but you can see my implementation here (search for "def Visit"): <https://github.com/righthandabacus/stealweb/blob/master/fakechrome.py>