# Cefpython GetText() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromium, cefpython

Hello everyone I am trying to print to the console the html of url. I took the code from tutorial.py that free in the [open source](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tutorial.py).
That is the class:

```
class LoadHandler(object):
    def OnLoadingStateChange(self, browser, is_loading, **_):
        """Called when the loading state has changed."""
        if not is_loading:
            # Loading is complete. DOM is ready.
            # js_print(browser, "Python", "OnLoadingStateChange", "Loading is complete")
            print('ready')
            print(browser.GetMainFrame().GetText())
```

and I added the two last lines:

```
print('ready')
print(browser.GetMainFrame().GetText())
```

When I run the code I get an ERROR massage:

> TypeError: GetText() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

I saw in the documentation that I need to give to the function parameter `StringVisitor`
(https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/Frame.md#gettext)

**What is the `StringVisitor` and how can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

`StringVisitor` is an object of a class that implemented `Visit()` method. Below is what you want to do:

```python
class Visitor(object)
    def Visit(self, value):
        print(value)
myvisitor = Visitor()
class LoadHandler(object):
    def OnLoadingStateChange(self, browser, is_loading, **_):
        """Called when the loading state has changed."""
        if not is_loading:
            # Loading is complete. DOM is ready.
            print('ready')
            browser.GetMainFrame().GetText(myvisitor)
```

It looks strange to put `myvisitor` outside the `OnLoadingStateChange()` function but it is one of the many ways to keep that object alive after the `GetText()` function returns, for the reason that `GetText()` is asynchronous.

You need to use `StringVisitor` in `cefpython` because many CEF functions are asynchronous, namely, then return immediately without finishing what you want them to do. They will call your *callback functions* when the actual work is done. In your example, when the text prepared by `GetText()` is ready, it will call the `Visit()` method in your `StringVisitor` object. This also means you need to think the other way in your program's flow.

(I have answered a similar question in [Need to get HTML source as string CEFPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788353/need-to-get-html-source-as-string-cefpython/48832650#48832650))